# Fore-edge painting package for books?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, margins, path-clipping

I would like to add fore-edge painting to the edge of each page, so that when the pages are fanned, it reveals text or an image.  It seems it would be easy enough to slice up an image(Tikz/PGF), or text, into the appropriate number of slices and place them at the leaf edges. However, I have no experience in writing packages, classes, or styles.

For example:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fore-edge_painting

http://typophile.com/node/56855

Any thoughts?

Comment: Rather, how do you actually do this? I doubt regular printers can do it... :P

Comment: It could be possible if you print some marks and then cut all the pages, as publishers do with books to have the actual book size.

Comment: A home computer printer cannot do it, unless it does 'borderless' like many photo printers do, but cut pages as in professional printing would have no problem.

Comment: @user44174 -- but the edges of books are trimmed *after* printing.  coordinating this with the printing house might be complicated; at the very least, it would likely be expensive, since it would involve manual setup and quality checking.  (note that both links given in the question specify *painting*, not *printing*.)

Comment: @barbara beeton - Aren't these normal considerations? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bleed_(printing) (I have no direct experience with this.)

Comment: @user44174 -- from the page you cite: "Often the paper is trimmed after printing to ensure the ink runs fully to the edge and does not stop short of it."  but it doesn't say how much overlap there is at the edge; "bleed" usually assumes rather a wide area of print is left inside the edge.  edge-painting, on the other hand, leaves little more than a whisper of ink/paint at the edge of the page, so that it's not really obvious when one looks at the front of the page.  this level of precision isn't "usual" in most print shops.

Comment: @user44174 Indeed, the bleed is used precisely because it is difficult to predict exactly where the page will be trimmed in the final form...

Comment: Please see pictures and pages 105-109 in `master?.pdf` in [this old book](http://striz7.fame.utb.cz/courses/dep/soubory/tex-and-friends.rar) from 2007. It used `latex`+`dvips` conversion. I used two methods, I called them *strip* and *portion*. I haven't found time to rewrite these ideas for a new engine, `pdflatex`, `xelatex` or `lualatex`. It could be done, if there would be a request for it.

Answer (score 3):

It can be done by using the packages `everypage` by Sergio Callegari and `tikz` by Till Tantau wich includes `epslatex` by Keith Reckdahl. For the example I have used package `lipsum` by Patrick Happe to generate the dummy text and a photograph of an [orchid](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/53131296/passionis.pdf) made by myself.

The idea is to make slices of the image with the option `viewport` of `\includegraphics`, to position it on the page with the options `remember picture` and `overlay` of `\tikz` and add it to every page with `\AddEverypageHook` of `everypage`. Since it is obviously for a book, it must go only on the odd pages, and this must be tested.

The dificulty is to take a different slice every time. I could not use macros as options for `viewport` so I have had to use counters. I have set the thickness of the slices to 10 pt.

It must be compiled two times.

```
\documentclass{book}

%% compile two times
%% image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/53131296/passionis.pdf

\usepackage{everypage}% by Sergio Callegari
\usepackage{tikz}%      by Till Tantau, wich includes epslatex by Keith Reckdahl
\usepackage{lipsum}%    by Patrick Happe

\newcounter{lowleftx}\setcounter{lowleftx}{0}
\newcounter{uprightx}\setcounter{uprightx}{10}

  \AddEverypageHook{%
    \ifodd\arabic{page}
      %% Then
           \tikz[remember picture,overlay]
                \path (current page.east)
                      node{\includegraphics[viewport=\value{lowleftx} 0 \value{uprightx} 841.890, clip=true]{passionis.pdf}}
                      \pgfextra{\addtocounter{lowleftx}{10}\addtocounter{uprightx}{10}};
    \fi}

\begin{document}

\foreach \x in {1,...,61}{\lipsum[1-10]}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice. I did a similar thing by moving a clipping window in the TikZ picture, made a book for some UX design.

Comment: @percusse Thank you very much. I am new here, so receiving positive comment is very encouraging.